# "unterminated `s' command" when doing substitution with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm trying to run the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's?^?'`pwd`'/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/?; s?$?.jpg?' test.txt > voc.2012.test
```

But it is responding with an error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated `s' command
```

What is the cause of this error and what can I do to correct it?

Comment: Does the output of `pwd` contain a space?

Answer (score 1):

If the output of `pwd` contains a space or other whitespace character, then this would split up the `sed` expression into at least two parts.  The first part would be an incomplete `s` command, and the second part would be taken as a filename.

This happens because the command substitution (the back-ticked `pwd`) is unquoted, i.e. it occurs *outside* of any single or double quote.

To remedy this, double quote the command substitution:

```
sed 's?^?'"$(pwd)"'/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/?; s?$?.jpg?' test.txt
```

You may also choose to use the `$PWD` variable:

```
sed 's?^?'"$PWD"'/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/?; s?$?.jpg?' test.txt
```

However, it looks as if you're just prepending a pathname and appending a filename suffix to every line in a file.

This could be done safer using `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf("%s/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/%s.jpg\n", ENVIRON["PWD"], $0) }' test.txt
```

This would work even if `$PWD` or the lines read from `test.txt` contained `?`, spaces, or strings that could be interpreted as regular expressions.

Testing:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/shell-yash.Oeo3joN3
```

```
$ cat test.txt
hello world
sunny afternoon
bumbling bees
```

```
$ awk '{ printf("%s/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/%s.jpg\n", ENVIRON["PWD"], $0) }' test.txt
/tmp/shell-yash.Oeo3joN3/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/hello world.jpg
/tmp/shell-yash.Oeo3joN3/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/sunny afternoon.jpg
/tmp/shell-yash.Oeo3joN3/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/bumbling bees.jpg
```